# Need Fix in Pictures Theme homepage

Tags: html, css

I am currently working on a Tumblr Theme for images only, but I can't get the home page fixed,

Here's how my homepage look:
http://tinyurl.com/bpm7uph

See the empty spaces in between images,

I want it to like like this:
i.imgur.com/dJWDR.jpg

and here's my css file:
http://tinyurl.com/8s9cfyx

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The generally agreed method for creating a layout like you want is to use something jQuery Masonry.

http://masonry.desandro.com/

To do it manually with only CSS you'd simply have to create two columns and add your items individually to each column. Obviously this isn't a great dynamic solution.

Comment: done, actually I clicked the Vote Up button and it said you need atleast 15 rep to do that, now Best Answer selected